# Advice on start-up package negotiation in the UK

Tags: job, united-kingdom, lecturer, negotiation

I just got a lecturer position at UK university. However, coming from the clinical field, I have no idea what items I need to negotiate. I know the research part of it but my colleague told me it is not only lab space but I also have to negotiate equipment and consumables.
I will do teaching but I have just realized that I need to negotiate the teaching package and I have no idea what things I can negotiate

I have read many things but it is only for US universities.

I'd appreciate some guidance on this as I negotiate a startup package at a UK university.

Answer (score 4):

How much towards consumables and equipment you might reasonably expect is going to be discipline specific. How much teaching you are expected to do is going to be discipline and institution specific. Things will also be dependent on what level you are coming in at and whether the university in question is a teaching or research focused institution.

For an overview you might like to consult [Acton SE, Bell AJ, Toseland CP, Twelvetrees A. A survey of new PIs in the UK. Elife. 2019 Sep 20;8:e46827](https://elifesciences.org/articles/46827).

In addition to lab/office space, other things you might want to consider is large equipment, cash  (which would be used for consumables, travel, computers, small equipment), PhD students and teaching relief.

In terms of large equipment, the approach is usually - if you absolutely need it to do your research, we'll help you find a way to get access to it. This might be buying something or promising you access to someone else's, it might be promising to put up the match funding an equipment grant would require.

In terms of students, preliminary data for your first grant will almost certainly come from a PhD student. Many places will allocate a studentship to a new lecturer. If this isn't the case, you'll need to find out what the situation is with access to PhD programs like DTPs (doctoral training programs), are you allowed to apply to them? Can it be arranged such that you are co-supervisor if a certain level of experience is required?  Is there a way to prioritise your applications?

Cash is generally very limited. I got £10k ten years ago, and that was fairly typical, and things havn't changed much since. Although I did also get a PhD studentship that came with £5k/year research costs.

Finally teaching. In most places you will eventually be expected to spend 40-50% of your time teaching. For a sense of scale a year is approx 1600 working hours, so 40% is 640 hours. We get 2 hours prep for each hour teaching plus 20 minutes a student marking time, so that's at least 100 contact hours. But few research focused places will require that in year one. So you can negotiate how long after you start your job you'll have to start teaching, and how quickly your load will increase. So I negotiated 0 hours in my first year, 20 in my second, 50 in my third, 100 in my fourth.

An final important thing to consider is what your probation (read tenure) criteria will be. How is success going to be judged and over what time scale?

One last thing.

Get. Everything. In. Writing.

Do not rely on anyone's say so. Particularly be aware of heads of department promising things they don't actaully have the power to deliver.

Answer (score 1):

There is normally no negotiation for positions of Lecturer in the UK. Your salary is determined by HRs and you normally start at the bottom of the grade. There is normally no startup package.

Congratulations on getting this position. Welcome to the UK academia.